# Integrating Mapbox with .NET MAUI

Tags: xamarin.forms, mapbox, mapbox-android, maui, .net-maui

I am currently developping an native Android app using Mapbox with Visual Studio (using some Mapbox nugets). I have to do the whole dev to address iOS customers but [Xamarin.Forms nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.Mapbox.Forms/) version of Mapbox is out of date, both Android & iOS SDKs have been updated since.

As Microsoft has just released the first [.NET MAUI Release Candidate RC1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-maui-rc-1/), i.e. the successor of **Xamarin.Forms**, I would like to start over a new project so I can manage one development pipeline to deploy on either Android or iOS afterwards.

So I open this thread in order to share help to embbed Mapbox in a fresh new .NET MAUI project.

**How should we proceed to simply display a Mapbox map view with a .NET MAUI project?**
Thank you!

Comment: I'll describe what needs to be done. Anything that can be integrated into a java (or objective c on iOS) app, can be integrated into a Maui (or Xamarin) app. For Xamarin, this requires mostly code in platform-specific (Android) project. For Maui, the equivalent is code wrapped in `#if Android`, that implements a custom handler. Someone needs to take the source code of that Xamarin Mapbox nuget, and change the xamarin custom renderer logic to Maui custom handler logic. ...

Comment: ... And because the Mapbox SDK has been updated, the [Java library bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/) must be regenerated. Likewise for the iOS library bindings. (I'm busy on a project that won't switch to Maui for another six months, so I don't have time to do this myself.)

Comment: Thank for the feedback. Is there any unofficial Xamarin Forms implementation of Mapbox using both SDKs? It could be useful to have a look about how it has been done in Forms in order to redo in MAUI.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for now is implementing a Maui Blazor app and using a BlazorWebView to put a MapBox in your page.

See [Build a .NET MAUI Blazor app documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/maui?view=aspnetcore-6.0)